# elements in HTML parsed twice using JSON

Tags: android, html, json

My website contains of 149 of these tags

```
<!-- Begin Module Image -->
  <div class="module-img">                          
     <a href="http://prodigy.co.id/news/events/youtube-viewer-event/" >
        <img src="http://prodigy.co.id/wp-content/uploads/Prodigy_Sticky_YoutubeViewer.png" width="280" height="150" alt="Youtube Viewer Event!" />
        <span></span>
     </a>                           
     <div class="lightboxLink">
      <a class="popLink boxLink" href="http://prodigy.co.id/wp-content/uploads/Prodigy_Sticky_YoutubeViewer.png" data-rel="prettyPhoto[Youtube Viewer Event!]" title="Youtube Viewer Event!"></a>
     </div>                         
     <div class="thumbLink">
        <a class="popLink" href="http://prodigy.co.id/news/events/youtube-viewer-event/" title="Full Post"></a>
     </div>                         
  </div>                            
<!-- End Module Image -->
```

Here's my parser:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(Server.EXPLORE_LINK).timeout(10 * 1000).get();

  Elements divs = document.select("div[class=module-img] a[href]");

     for (Element div : divs) {
         try {
             href = div.attr("href");
             Elements a = document.select("a[href=" + href + "] img[src]");
             src = a.attr("src");

             if (!src.startsWith("http://"))
             src = src.substring(src.indexOf("http://"));

             hrefs.add(href);
             srcs.add(src);

          } catch (Exception any) {
             any.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

I want my href to be `http://prodigy.co.id/news/events/youtube-viewer-event/`, and src to be `http://prodigy.co.id/wp-content/uploads/Prodigy_Sticky_YoutubeViewer.png` for 149 times. At this point I'm completely confused that the size of element `divs` are 444, not 149 as it should be.

Forgive my laziness but I'm new in this JSON thing and I've been googling around for hours looking for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the size is 444? It would make sense if it is 447.

Your selector is valid for all three links in your HTML code. A space means that there can be any number of elements in between. If you want to select direct child nodes only you have to use '>' in between:

```
Elements divs = document.select("div[class=module-img] > a[href]");
```

PS: you could use

```
.classname
```

instead of

```
div[class=classname]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this jsoup API but looking at the selector you used, it seems that you're querying for ALL  tags that are DESCENDED from `<div class="module-img">`. Note that there are 3 `<a>` inside each module. This would explain the number 444 as 148x3=444. (You said there are 149, but perhaps the first occurrence or the last is not being counted.)

Anyway, try this:

```
Elements divs = document.select("div[class=module-img] > a[href]");
```

It should list only `<a>` children that are DIRECT DESCENDING from given `<div>`.

Here's [more](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) about selectors and combinators.